# processing json into html

Tags: jquery, json

I was able to pull the deals from the groupon api with the following code

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'https://api.groupon.com/v2/deals.json?    client_id=b252ad3634a4ab2985b79d230ccc4e49a3ea9d19&show=all&division_id=los-angeles',
async: false,
jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: 'jsonp',
});
```

now how do I add the deal info into a html div so i can style it with css. I only need some of the data such as deal title, tipping point, price etc.. thanks in advance

Comment: i will also need the deal img, does this require anything special since it's not plain text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a success callback for the ajax request, then use the `deals` data returned from the server to render the data.

The deals data returned from the server has many properties like `type`, `finePrint`, `announcementTitle`, `dealUrl`, `highlightsHtml`, `pitchHtml`, `placementPriority`, `redemptionLocation`, `startAt`, `status`, `endAt` etc, you can use it to create an view representation and append it to the view

In the below example I'm using the `highlightsHtml` to display the deal highlights

```
<div id="result">
</div>
```

then

```
var $result = $('#result')
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.groupon.com/v2/deals.json?client_id=b252ad3634a4ab2985b79d230ccc4e49a3ea9d19&show=all&division_id=los-angeles',
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data)
    $.each(data.deals, function(idx, deal){
        var html = '<div class="deal"><h3>' + deal.announcementTitle+ '</h3><div class="fineprint">' + deal.finePrint + '</div><div class="footer"><img src="' + deal.mediumImageUrl + '"/></div></div>'
        $result.append(html)
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4Pck9/)

Comment: so how do I decide what info I want ? where do I put the code ?

Comment: so how can i seperate the data ? the code you provided puts all the data for the deals in one div, if i'm going to be able to style it the way i want, i'm going to have to place each deal into a seperate div or maybe i can use a list ul & li

Comment: @user2680299 you can create a html like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4Pck9/2/ or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4Pck9/3/ like these you can enhance the view as much as you want

Comment: thank you so much, you have taught me alot, one more thing, i cant seem to get it to work on my local file in chrome, i dont have it on my localhost server, just on my local c drive on my computer, dont know why ?

Comment: @user2680299 check your browser console to see whether there is any error

Answer (score 3):

The `async: false` option is deprecated, and defeats the purpose of AJAX. Regardless, JSONP does not support a synchronous call anyway. Simply use the [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method to retrieve the data, then write it to the DOM in a success callback.

By looking at the returned data (by logging it to the console using `console.log`, and opening your browser's JS console), and by playing around with the functions listed in the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/), you can keep tweaking things until you get the desired effect. The code below looks at a few of the properties of the returned object, and sticks them into the DOM using the methods [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append), [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend), and [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html).

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/kr26w/2/)

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("https://api.groupon.com/v2/deals.json?callback=?", {
        client_id: "b252ad3634a4ab2985b79d230ccc4e49a3ea9d19",
        show: "all",
        division_id: "los-angeles"
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        // do whatever processing you need to do to the data
        // right here, then drop it in the div
        $.each(data.deals, function (i, v) {
            $title = $("<h2/>", {
                html: v.title,
                class: "heading"
            });
            $img = $("<img/>", {
                src: v.mediumImageUrl
            });
            $deal = $("<div/>", {
                html: v.highlightsHtml + v.pitchHtml
            });
            $("#main").append($deal);
            $deal.prepend($title, $img);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: can you give me some code that will place each deal into a separate div and then separate the deal info into separate div's in side the main div ? not to good with jquery or json, thanks

Comment: @user2680299 Try something. If it doesn't work I can try and help you debug it, but I won't write it for you. That's not what SO is for, and if that's what you're looking for you're better off hiring a developer, because we usually don't work for free. Take a look at [the Help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance formulating your question

Comment: i guess your right, i've been trying to figure this out for sometime, its for a project at work, i've been looking for tutorials on like to help me with the Groupon API, but theirs nothing out there, i guess i can learn more about jquery, i just dont have time right now, thanks for helping me though

Comment: @user2680299 The best way to make progress quickly is to keep trying things until they work, and carefully noting the errors displayed in your console when it doesn't work. Have a look at my [updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/kr26w/1/) and see if it helps you move forward a bit. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Try knockoutjs. You can easily convert your Ajax to a view model in javascript and display it on the screen with styling.